# How to properly initialize an ErrorEvent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dispatchevent

I need to fire an `ErrorEvent` programmatically, but can't figure out how to initialize the properties of the event. The properties are readonly, and `initEvent()` only initializes the event type, whether it bubbles, and if it's cancellable.

I tried

```
var myErrorEvent = new ErrorEvent("error", new Error("This is my error"));
```

and

```
myErrorEvent.initEvent("error", false, true, new Error("This is my error"));
```

or

```
// This function would be defined in IE only. Could not find it in Chrome.
myErrorEvent.initErrorEvent("error", false, true, "This is my error", "myfile.js", 1234);
```

I tried many other things, but could not get the properties of the `ErrorEvent` to be set properly.

Is this even feasible?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You were close! The 2nd argument to the `ErrorEvent` constructor is an object with the properties you want to set, like this:

```
var error = new ErrorEvent('oh nose', {
    error : new Error('AAAHHHH'),
    message : 'A monkey is throwing bananas at me!',
    lineno : 402,
    filename : 'closet.html'
});
```

For the full set of properties, see [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#erroreventinit).

Comment: I could only rethrow that error when replacing "oh nose" with "error" and then that only worked on Chrome... I wish we had any kind of error handling standard...