# How to create an ErrorEvent in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, typescript-typings

According to this post

[How to properly initialize en ErrorEvent in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554607/how-to-properly-initialize-en-errorevent-in-javascript)

You should be able to create an `EventError` with this code:

```
var error = new ErrorEvent('oh nose', {
    error : new Error('AAAHHHH'),
    message : 'A monkey is throwing bananas at me!',
    lineno : 402,
    filename : 'closet.html'
});
```

However, if you try this in the TypeScript playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20error%20%3D%20new%20ErrorEvent('oh%20nose'%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20error%20%3A%20new%20Error('AAAHHHH')%2C%0A%20%20%20%20message%20%3A%20'A%20monkey%20is%20throwing%20bananas%20at%20me!'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20lineno%20%3A%20402%2C%0A%20%20%20%20filename%20%3A%20'closet.html'%0A%7D)%3B

It says `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

Even this simple example does not compile:

```
var error = new ErrorEvent('oh nose');
```

I have tried to figure it out by looking at the Type Definition

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L9612

But can't figure it out.

What is missing to create a perfectly legal `EventError` in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3):

*lib.es6.d.ts* is not completely aligned with the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#the-errorevent-interface).

You should log an issue on [TypeScript's github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues), but for the time being you can edit *lib.es6.d.ts* to include the fix:

```
// add this interface
interface ErrorEventInit {
    // ...put the properties here...
}

// edit this declare var's new signature
declare var ErrorEvent: {
    new(type: string, eventInitDict?: ErrorEventInit): ErrorEvent;
    prototype: ErrorEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ErrorEvent is a type that extends from Event and uses ErrorEventInit inside. Here is the declaration 
https://github.com/microsoft/TSJS-lib-generator/blob/master/baselines/dom.generated.d.ts#L5410

Give this a try -

```
const errorInitEvent: ErrorEventInit = {
    error : new Error('AAAHHHH'),
    message : 'A monkey is throwing bananas at me!',
    lineno : 402,
    colno: 123,
    filename : 'closet.html'
};

const CustomErrorEvent = new ErrorEvent('MyErrEventType', errorInitEvent);
```